# In what way is Java "almost entirely nominally typed"?

Tags: java, typing

I read from [this article](http://cr.openjdk.java.net/~briangoetz/lambda/lambda-state-final.html) that "Java is almost entirely nominally typed". So there are structurally typed parts in Java.

Which are the nominal and structural parts of the Java type system?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to an earlier post by the same author - [removal of function types](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/lambda-dev/2010-July/001781.html):

> 1. There are two basic approaches to typing: nominal and structural.  The  identity of a nominal is based on its name; the identity of a
>      structural type  is based on what it is composed of (such as "tuple of
>      int, int" or "function  from int to float".)
>
> Most languages pick mostly nominal or mostly structural; there are not
>   a lot of languages that successfully mix nominal and structural
>   typing except  "around the edges."  Java is almost entirely nominal
>   (with a few exceptions:  **arrays are a structural type**, but at the
>   bottom there is always a nominal  element type; **generics have a mix of
>   nominal and structural too**, and this is  in fact part of the source of
>   many of people's complaints about generics.)

So, arrays and parts of generics are structural types.

I think the structural types may be something like `<T extends A & B>` being a supertype of `<T extends A>`, or `Object[]` being a supertype of `String[][]`. These type compatibilities are not based solely on their name.

Comment: thanks for Goetz link, helped to know their motivation: `If we added function types, it would immediately bifurcate the libraries`

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell Java is entirely nominally typed. 
Two objects are type compatible if they are of the same named type. In Java declaring classes:

```
class A {
    public int value;
}

class B {
    public int value;
}
```

provides you with nothing in the way of language constructs to exploit the equal members declared in the same order.

Whereas in C you can take advantage (under certain circumstances) of declaring `A` & `B` as `struct`s and their having the same binary layout meaning you can copy them over each other and form a `union` and exploit that overlap.